# Load page into a div ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The div doesnt load with the website using jquery load function. I want the website to load in the red div but its not.

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Nnauosp0AC

Comment: Your fiddle is blank, please post some code here.

Comment: Save the fiddle and share the link rather than using collaboration.